# How to remove Geonode Mapstore Viewer Plugins

Tags: mapping, geonode

I have been trying to remove the "Print" plugin from the map_viewer page by overriding the `localConfig.json` in the `_geonode_config.html` file.(See Attached).

After I remove it, a couple of print options remain in the map.
How can get rid of these print options checkboxes that apears in the map?

Images to describe the problem attached.

[image: before removing the plugin]

[image: after remove Print plugin]

This the code for overriding the `/src/my_geonode/templates/geonode-mapstore-client/_geonode_config.html` file.

```
    % extends 'geonode-mapstore-client/_geonode_config.html' %}
{% block override_local_config %}
<script>
 window.__GEONODE_CONFIG__.overrideLocalConfig = function(localConfig, _) {
 // Here the localConfig can be overridden and/or extended
 var removePluginName = "Print";
 var pluginPageName = "map_viewer";
 var pluginDatasetPage = "dataset_viewer"
 var newMapPlugins = [];
 var newDatasetPlugins = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < localConfig.plugins[pluginPageName].length; i++) {
 var currentPlugin = localConfig.plugins[pluginPageName][i];
 var isRemovePlugin = currentPlugin.name === removePluginName;
 if (!isRemovePlugin) {
 newMapPlugins.push(currentPlugin);
 }
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < localConfig.plugins[pluginDatasetPage].length; i++) {
 var currentPlugin = localConfig.plugins[pluginDatasetPage][i];
 var isRemovePlugin = currentPlugin.name === removePluginName;
 if (!isRemovePlugin) {
 newDatasetPlugins.push(currentPlugin);
 }
 }
 localConfig.plugins[pluginPageName] = newMapPlugins;
 localConfig.plugins[pluginDatasetPage] = newDatasetPlugins;
 return localConfig;
 };
</script>
{% endblock %
```

[See more details of the issue here](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client/issues/1656)